# SQL query LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Ok...  I always struggle with LEFT JOINS for some reason in SQL.

I have a simple query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as OpenedToday, c.Product_Line, c.Product_Code
FROM SFCase as c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code from SFCase) as p ON p.Product_Code = c.Product_Code
WHERE IsClosed = 'false'
AND DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(YEAR, CreatedDate)
AND DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedDate)
AND DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(DAY, CreatedDate)
GROUP BY c.Product_Line, c.Product_Code
```

What I'm expecting is a list of all Product_Code, with a count of how many cases were OpenedToday (including zero values).   Instead, I only get a list of those product codes that have cases opened today (only positive values).

When I run only the DISTINCT Product_Code, I get 70 results show.   However, running the full query, I only get 4 today.   I'd like to see all 70 results, along with zeros if no cases have been opened today.

What am I doing wrong with this join?

Charlie

Comment: Does SFCase only hold cases opened today? If not, how do you tell which cases were opened today - is there an opened_date, for example? Do you have a separate table to hold all products?

Comment: you are doing is opposite. use right outer join

Comment: Mark - actually, my real query had a bit more...  I tried to simplify it for the forums.  I've updated the question to show the full query...  I'm just checking the CreatedDate field to tell if it was opened today or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IsClosed='false' AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), CreatedDate)=0 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OpenedToday, 
       Product_Line, Product_Code
FROM SFCase
GROUP BY Product_Line, Product_Code
```

Comment: Nice, thanks Mark.   That does the trick.   It's going to take me a minute to understand that... definitely a different approach than what I was trying, but that seems to give me exactly what I'm looking for.   MANY THANKS!

Comment: Okay... after reading through that CASE statement... this makes perfect sense.   I like this approach... actually I think it may help me with some other queries I'm trying to manage that I've inherited.   I might be able to simplify them so that I can actually manage them haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  p.Product_Line, p.Product_Code,COUNT(*) as OpenedToday
FROM SFCase as c
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code from SFCase) as p 
ON p.Product_Code = c.Product_Code
GROUP BY p.Product_Line, p.Product_Code
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was giving the same results as what I had.